# Why does the tensor product pop up in the inverse image of modules?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

For sheaves of sets, the direct image has a simple left adjoint given by the usual colimit over bigger open sets.

But for modules over a sheaf of ringed, the inverse image sometimes involves tensoring the naive inverse image with the sheaf of rings. Why is this? Why does the tensor product pop up? What makes the naive inverse image stop being left adjoint to the direct image?

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ and $F$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules, then $f^{-1}F$ is a sheaf of $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y$- modules but not a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_X$ solve the problem.

Comment: @Cla sorry, could you explain how tensoring with $\mathcal O _X$ solves the problem, and why it is left adjoint?

Comment: To illustrate @Cla's point, and to see that tensoring is necessary, try as example $X= {{\mathop {\rm Spec}} ( \mathbb C)} $ and $Y= {{\mathop {\rm Spec}} ( \mathbb R)} $, $f$ the natural map, and  $F$ the $Y$-sheaf associated with the $\mathbb R$-module $\mathbb R$. Then is it clear that $f^{-1}F$ is not  a ${\mathcal O}_X$-module?

Comment: @peterag it's not really clear to me, sorry. Could you spell it out? Also, why does the direct image functor not need "fixing" as well?

Comment: Both spaces have just one point - right? on these spaces,  one can identify a sheaf with its stalk - here the stalk of $f^{-1}F$ at the unique point of $X$ is $\mathbb R$. This is not a module (vector space, here) over $\mathbb C$. But ${\mathbb C}\otimes_{\mathbb R}{\mathbb R}$ is.

Comment: To answer your second question if $B$ is an $A$-algebra, and $M$ a $B$-module, $M$ is automatically an $A$-module.

Comment: @peterag thanks for the detailed answers! If you'd like, post them as an answer so that I'll have something to accept.

Comment: glad to help - if I have time later (maybe over the weekend), I might write more as 'an answer,' unless somebody else does, if only to take this question off of the unanswered queue. best...

Comment: @peterag one last thing - how is $f_\ast \mathcal O_X$ an $\mathcal O_Y$-algebra?

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes then you have included in the definition a map $f_{\sharp}:\mathcal{O}_Y\to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ which makes $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ into an $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module.

Comment: @Cla sorry, I still don't understand. How does that map make $f_\ast \mathcal O_X$ into a $\mathcal O_Y$-module?

Comment: An $R$-module $M$ is a group in which a multiplication by elements of $R$ is defined. If you have a homomorphism $R\to S$ of rings then you can define a multiplication by elements of $R$ on $S$ by using this homomorphism ($S$ is actually an $R$-algebra).

Comment: For a reference for @Cla's comment, see Hartshorne's AG page 72, Definition of ringed space, and morphism - pay attention to the bit about morphisms inducing local homomorphisms on stalks.  (cont)

Comment: (cont) The condition makes the map on sheaves match up with the topological map: it rules out a kooky
$$  {{\mathop {\rm Spec}} ( \mathbb Q)} \rightarrow { {\mathop {\rm Spec}} } ( \mathbb Z_{(p)}),$$
with, on the underlying top. spaces,  $(0) \mapsto (p)$, instead of $(0) \mapsto (0)$, as it ought, and is key 
to the vital Prop 2.3 c), which says that to give a morphism between affine spaces is the same as giving a ring homomorphism on the corresponding rings.